# Match Route Only if specific Parameter

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to create a route that only matches if a specific parameter is used in the URL.

For example:

```
routes.MapRoute(
                name: "BannerAds",
                url: "Go/{Web}",
                defaults: new { controller = "CommunicationsAlias", action = "BannerAds", web = UrlParameter.Optional }
                );
```

I want the URL to match for http://www.domain.com/Go/Web?=111222

But not for http://www.domain.com/Go/Advertising

How do I change my route to function this way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would need to make that part of the url static in your route then:

```
routes.MapRoute(
                name: "BannerAds",
                url: "Go/Web",
                defaults: new { controller = "CommunicationsAlias", action = "BannerAds" }
            );
```

And then place that route above a your more general one:

```
routes.MapRoute(
                name: "BannerAds",
                url: "Go/{Web}",
                defaults: new { controller = "CommunicationsAlias", action = "BannerAds", web = UrlParameter.Optional }
                );
```

Comment: I'm confused - do I put the "Go/Web" directly above the "Go/{Web}" ?  When I try this, "http://www.domain.com/Go/Advertising" still gets directed to the BannerAds action.

Comment: Routes are tried from top to bottom, in order. If a match is found, then the matching route is selected.  So, you want your more specific routes at the top.  The `{Web}` route is more general than the `Web`.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to just do this:

```
routes.MapRoute(name: "BannerAds",
                url: "Go/Web",
                defaults: new { controller = "CommunicationsAlias", action = "BannerAds", web = UrlParameter.Optional });
```

And manually parse the query string in the controller like this:

```
public ActionResult BannerAds()
{
    string idStr = Request.QueryString.ToString().Trim('='); // strip of leading '='
    int id;
    if (!int.TryParse(idStr, out id))
    {
        return HttpNotFound();
    }

    ...
}
```

Comment: I did try this and get a "The route URL cannot start with a '/' or '~' character and it cannot contain a '?' character." error

Comment: @user547794 See my updated answer for a more complete solution

Answer (score 0):

like this

```
routes.MapRoute(
                name: "BannerAds",
                url: "Go/Web",
                defaults: new { controller = "CommunicationsAlias", action = "BannerAds", web = UrlParameter.Optional }
                );
```

if you actually only want to catch

http://www.domain.com/Go/Web?x=111222

then write the controller to check for query strings

**edit**

`?=111222` isn't a proper query string - I don't really get why you want to catch that - usually there is key value pair , like `?key=111222` or `?x=111222` when writing like that you can check for the value of `x` or `key` and if it equals 111222 , then do something